# Sorting is lost on page index change of a GridView asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, pagination

I have implemented **sorting** and **pagination** in a `GridView` control. The code is as below :

```
<asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" CssClass="Grid"                    
            AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="15" OnPageIndexChanging="grdAllRequests_PageIndexChanging"
            PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" OnSorting="grdAllRequests_Sorting" AllowSorting="True" 
            EmptyDataText="No data to show" ID="grdAllRequests" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            OnRowDataBound="grdAllRequests_RowDataBound">
```

Below is the **code behind** for pagination and sorting

```
protected void grdAllRequests_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grdAllRequests.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dtAllRequests"];

    BindDataBAL bind = new BindDataBAL();
    bind.BindGridData(grdAllRequests, dt);
}

protected void grdAllRequests_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtrslt = (DataTable)ViewState["dtAllRequests"];
    if (dtrslt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["sortdr"]) == "Asc")
        {
            dtrslt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " Desc";
            ViewState["sortdr"] = "Desc";
        }
        else
        {
            dtrslt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " Asc";
            ViewState["sortdr"] = "Asc";
        }
        ViewState["dtAllRequests"] = dtrslt;
        grdAllRequests.DataSource = dtrslt;
        grdAllRequests.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Now the issue is when i click on any header the sorting is performed correctly but when i try to navigate to next page then the sorting is lost. Not sure what is going wrong. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `DefaultView.ToTable();`

```
dtrslt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " Desc";
dtrslt = dtrslt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```